# How to create a laravel API for multiple array of an object

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, eloquent

I am creating a laravel multiple array of an object API but my controller gives an error

Below is the request

```
[
    {
    "ProductTitle": "Clarks Men's Tilden Cap Oxford shoe",
    "ProductColor": "Dark tan leather",
    "ProductImage": "imageurl"
         }
         ,
    {
    "ProductTitle": "Clarks Men's Tilden Cap Oxford shoe",
    "ProductColor": "Dark tan leather",
    "ProductImage": "imageurl"
        }
]
```

My API store controller is as below

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {



        $input = $request;


        $validator = Validator::make($input,  [
            'ProductTitle' => 'required',
            'ProductColor' => 'required',
            'ProductImage' => 'required'
             ]);


        if($validator->fails()){
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());       
        }
        $cartdetails=shopCartDetails::create($request->all());

        return $this->sendResponse( $cartdetails,'Great success! cart details posted'); 

      }
```

Am getting error

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be
>   of the type array, object given,

the results have now changed to

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Validation Error.",
    "data": {
        "ProductTitle": [
            "The product title field is required."
        ],
        "ProductColor": [
            "The product color field is required."
        ],
        "ProductImage": [
            "The product image field is required."
        ]

    } }
```

seems it gets only one array

Comment: The above one is request ?

Comment: yes that is the request am expecting

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? `all()` is supposed to return an `array` not an `object`. Do a `dd($input)` to see what's there.

Comment: @azeós am using 5.8 please  any suggestion

Comment: @azeós changed to $input=$request still same error

Comment: Leave it as `$input = $request->all();`, but after that line make a `dd($input)` so we can see what's there.

Comment: @azeós done that seems to be an array

Comment: Please copy the exact result and paste it on your question.

Comment: @azeós now it validates only the first array

Comment: Change `$input = $request;` to `$input = $request->all();` Do a `dd` of that, `$request` only is not correct.

Comment: @azeós I have tried dd()    the array seems to be [ 0=>[] 1=>[] ]

Comment: That's strange. Show us your HTML code. Which `Request` are you using? Paste your `use` line that's at the top of the file.

Comment: @azeós are you on skype?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the full request object instead of the values to your validator

`Validator::make($request->all()...`

You can validate arrays (of objects) using * like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),  [
    '*.ProductTitle' => 'required',
    '*.ProductColor' => 'required',
    '*.ProductImage' => 'required'
]);
```